# Расширение для хрома которое вытаскивает реквесты с вкладки network в devtools

Tags: jquery, webbrowser, расширения

Нужно сделать расширение для хрома которое  вытаскивает реквесты с вкладки network в devtools. Никак не могу вытащить хоть что то с network.

Comment: Покажите ваш код, что у вас конкретно не получается?